# How to ignore QTapGesture after QTapAndHoldGesture

Tags: c++, qt, touch, qt5, gesture

I want to get `QTapAndHoldGesture` and `QTapGesture` in my widget
and do different thing as reaction on these gestures.
So I override `QWidget::event` method and add such code:

```
 bool event(QEvent *event) override {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture) {
      auto g_event = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
      qDebug() << "GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures " << g_event->gestures().size() << ", active: " << g_event->activeGestures();
      if (auto g = qobject_cast<QTapGesture *>(g_event->gesture(Qt::TapGesture))) {
        g_event->accept(g);
        return true;
      }
      if (auto g = qobject_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture *>(g_event->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))) {
        if (g->state() == Qt::GestureFinished) {
                qDebug("FINISHED!!!");
                g->setGestureCancelPolicy(QGesture::CancelAllInContext);
        }
        g_event->accept(g);
        return true;
      }
```

The problem is that I get not wanted `QTapGesture` at the end of `QTapAndHoldGesture`.

It looks like this:

```
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureStarted,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureUpdated,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
mouse event x  773 , y  493
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureUpdated,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
...
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureUpdated,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapAndHoldGesture(state=GestureStarted,hotSpot=773,493,position=773,493,timeout=700))
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapAndHoldGesture(state=GestureFinished,hotSpot=773,493,position=773,493,timeout=700))
FINISHED!!!
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureUpdated,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureUpdated,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
GestureEvent BEGIN: gestures  1 , active:  (QTapGesture(state=GestureFinished,hotSpot=773.396,492.884,position=773.396,492.884))
```

As you see at start I got `QTapGesture` in started state, then `QTapGesture` in updated state, after that `QTapAndHoldGesture` and after that `QTabGesture` finished.

I need some way to ignore it. But I don't see how without re-implementing of gesture framework: collect position and time of event and filter events based on this information. Because of I receive gestures one by one and can not connect `QTapGesture` and `QTapAndHoldGesture`.

So is it possible to ignore `QTapGesture` after `QTapAndHoldGesture` without collecting information about position and time of `QGestureEvent`?

Comment: So... your problem is that a TapAndHoldGesture also automatically fires off a few "normal" TapGestures, correct?

Comment: @TheSHEEEP To be correct, only one `TapGeasture` with `Finished` hurts me, all other I can ignore using `state() != Finished` check.

Comment: If you ignore all others anyway, why not ignore the Finished one, too? Just listen to the QTapAndHoldGestures, it has both Started and Finished. And I assume also Updates (you're not printing those).

Comment: @TheSHEEEP Because, as I said in question, I need separate reaction on `Tap` and `TapAndHold`. So I also react on `Tap` with state == finished. But in case of `TapAndHold` I have spurious `Tap` at the end. So I can not distinguish between normal Tap with finished and spurious tap with finished. For example on swipe gesture you get Tap started, Tap updated, but never Tap finished.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case I think there really is no way other than to manually ignore `TapGesture` with `Finished` if there has been a `TapAndHold` with `Finished` X milliseconds before that. Or, maybe easier to write & read, ignore the action that would normally be done on a `TapGesture` with `Finished` if the other action from `TapAndHold` has been done within the last X milliseconds.

Comment: I assume the underlying problem being that Qt has no way to know when starting out if a Gesture is going to be one or the other, so it has to report on both.

Answer (score 6):

Because `QTapAndHoldGesture` gesture also requires a "Tap", it is expected to receive both:

- QTapAndHoldGesture first, when the user holds for a certain time (end of a timer)
- QTapGesture then, when the user releases the touch

Because they will always be received in that order, you can use that fact, to filter or cancel the QTapGesture which will be started, but not finished, when you receive QTapAndHoldGesture is validated (i.e. finished).

No need for time or position information, if you are managing a single touch point (Disclaimer: The following is untested).

```
bool MyClass::event(QEvent *event) override
{
    // QPointer in case we receive partial events. Should remove "isNull()" keys at some point.
    static QMap<QPointer<QTapGesture*>, bool> tapGestures;
    if (event->type() != QEvent::Gesture)
        return QQuickItem::event(event);

    auto g_event = static_cast<QGestureEvent *>(event);
    if (auto g = qobject_cast<QTapGesture *>(g_event->gesture(Qt::TapGesture))) {
        // A TapAndHold was triggered during that tap... let's ignore it
        if (tapGestures.value(g))
            g_event->ignore(g); // Or handle as you like

        if (g->state() == Qt::GestureFinished || g->state() == Qt::GestureCancelled)
            tapGestures.remove(g);
        else if (!tapGestures.contains(g))
            tapGestures.insert(g, false);

        g_event->accept(g);
        return true;
    }

    if (auto g = qobject_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture *>(g_event->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))) {
        // Probably not needed if the gesture handle doesn't conflict with another component
        //if (g->state() == Qt::GestureFinished)
        //    g->setGestureCancelPolicy(QGesture::CancelAllInContext);

        // Mark all QTapGesture in progress to be ignored
        for (auto it = tapGestures.begin(); it != tapGestures.end(); ++it)
            it.value() = true;

        g_event->accept(g);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All gestures are available in [QGestureManager class](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qgesturemanager.cpp.html#306), so there may be a way to access it.

There is also the GestureOverride event type, but I believe that in your case it will not be triggered.